# How to calculate the time difference with two times?

Tags: php, date-arithmetic

im getting the time with this function :

```
time();
```

and im storaging this times in my database,

How can i calculate the difference of current and old date from the database ?

i need results like this : 1 min 10 sec ago

Comment: The term you want to search for is "date arithmetic".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `$time1` and `$time2` are both generated by `time()` » UNIX_TIMESTAMP(), you can use:

```
$diff = $time1 - $time2;
```

The difference will be in seconds.

Comment: With the gmdate("i:s",$diff); we can find the difference like this : 00:00

Thank you for your answer !

Answer (score 0):

[Carbon](https://github.com/briannesbitt/Carbon) is an exceedingly useful date/time library for PHP. It has a very handy "difference for humans" that will output that sort of difference string. https://github.com/briannesbitt/Carbon#api-humandiff